# Mysql Divide the total sum of one column being created by another column being created

Tags: mysql, count, average

I have a table with a bunch of assets by date,

I am:

1.- selecting and grouping by date <- complete

2.- counting all the assets in a giving date alias: `count_by_date` <- complete

3.- getting the total amount of people that will receive the assets and dividing that number by the count of assets per date, alias: `end_result` <- this is the problem I'm having.

```
SELECT 
dates, 
COUNT(*) AS `count_by_date`,
SUM(`amount_of_people`) / `count_by_date` AS `end_result`
FROM example_table
GROUP BY dates;
```

Is that even possible?

If it is, how can this work?

I marked specifically what part of the select I'm having trouble with and which is completed and working fine.

Comment: Is `b` one of your column?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not using `AVG(b)`?

Comment: If you have a space in an alias, you need to escape it: `AS \`average b\` `

Comment: stackFan yes b is a column I renamed for better understanding, Barmar AVG will get me the average of people so SUM(people) / COUNT(people) I don't want that and yes I know I have to add a backtick for column names adding the format in stack overflow is a little tricky.

Comment: I forgot to thank you all :) thank you. I'm still looking into this so any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use alias  column name in select   you must repeat the code

```
    SELECT 
    dates, COUNT(*) AS count_by_date
    , SUM(b) / COUNT(*) AS average 
    FROM example_table
    GROUP BY dates;
```

the db engine  resolve the alias  name after the select clause is evalueted so during the evaluation the alias of columns name are not knowed  by the select clause

Comment: yeah I thought I had to repeat the code, but since the data I'm querying is a little lengthy it causes the query to timeout.

Comment: the timeout is not  related  to the code repeating  .. the db engine  .. do the calculation one time on only  ..  ..

Comment: sorry to say you are wrong scaisEdge, MySQL will not be aware the first part of the statement is related to the second. Thanks anyway :).

Comment: @Moises  . i don't uderstand you comment  .. if my code don't work show me the exact error message , if produce wrong result show me the actual result and the expected  result  based on a coherent data sample

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this would be by using alias table if you want to perform calculations with your alias names for columns.

For example:

```
SELECT t.dates, t.total/t.count_by_date  AS avg
FROM
(SELECT dates,COUNT(*) AS count_by_date,SUM(b) AS total
FROM
example_table b
GROUP BY dates )
AS t;
```